# c# web browser insert text into textarea

Tags: c#, insert, textarea

how to insert text into textarea using .net web browser ?
i've tried many ways, but none of them worked

here's my try

```
HtmlElement element4 = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("description");
element4.SetAttribute("value", "text");
```

but as i said none of them worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
element4.InnerText = "text";
```

Assuming `GetElementById` worked and you have a valid reference in `element4`, this should do it.

Comment: just tried it out and got this error: Property is not supported on this type of HtmlElement. here's textarea code: <textarea maxlength="255" id="description" name="description" cols="20" rows="2" role="textbox" multiline="true" class="FormElement"></textarea>